# how to build a list which looks like (list "a" "aa" "aaa" "aaaa" "aaaaa")

Tags: racket

The requirement is to use drracket (scheme) build-list to produce `(list "a" "aa" "aaa" "aaaa" "aaaaa")`.

I tried `foldr` but only give "aaaaa"

```
(define (build-a-string n)
  (foldr string-append "" (build-list n "a")))
```

Comment: Have you tried any other code?

Comment: Welcome to SO! To help others answer your question, please provide some code showing what you've tried so far. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Without any more requirements, what's the matter with `(list "a" "aa" "aaa" "aaaa" "aaaaa")` which produces `("a" "aa" "aaa" "aaaa" "aaaaa")`?

Answer (score 0):

```
(build-list 5 (lambda (i)
                (make-string (add1 i) #\a)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses "fold":

```
#lang racket

(define (build-as n)
  (for/fold ([as '("")]) ([_ n])
    (define last-a (first as))
    (define new-a  (string-append "a" last-a))
    (cons new-a as)))    

(build-as 5)
```

And here is the short version:

```
(define (build-as n)
  (for/fold ([as '("")]) ([_ n])
    (cons (string-append "a" (first as)) as)))
```